# Rails: Show SQL Queries in Production Log

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, production-environment

How can we enabled SQL query logging in production environment?

Thanks,

Imran

Comment: I have tried different log_levels `(config.log_level)` with no luck.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In your `environments/production.rb`

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

Remember you need to restart the web server to apply the changes.

Comment: Thanks Simone. It works. I was trying with the numbers (0-4).

Comment: accept the answer because it's the good answer like you explain

Comment: Yes, I am trying but getting this message "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes" and waiting for this lag to get past :).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Running production via `rails s -e production`

Answer (score 2):

If you're setting the production log level to `debug`, I would recommend you to set the log level with an environment variable. Log level **debug is much bigger** than info and it can easily grow out of control or quotas if you're using a log service. So, with an environment variable you can change it faster only restarting rails, without the need for changing the code and deploy:

```
config.log_level = (ENV['LOG_LEVEL'] || :debug)
```

This way, you optionally set the environment variable `LOG_LEVEL` to change it.

Comment: Thank you for your info!; For production, default = :info would be better ?